# How to delete rows dynamically using epplus?

Tags: vb.net, epplus

Here I am trying to delete rows that have '*' value in any cell of that row.
below is my code..

This is for headers:

```
If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        Dim k As Integer = 0
        For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            If Not skip.Contains(j) Then
                If columnNames.Count > 0 AndAlso columnNames.Count = (ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - skip.Count) Then
                    strTitle = columnNames(k)
                Else
                    strTitle = ds.Tables(0).Columns(j).ColumnName.Replace("_", " ")
                End If
                worksheet5.Cells(p, k + 1).Value = strTitle
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next
```

Row starts here:

```
        Dim i As Integer = p + 1
        For Each r As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            If Not r.ToString().Contains("*") Then

                k = 0
                For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                    If Not skip.Contains(j) Then
                        'If Not r.Item(j).ToString().Contains("*") Then
                        If r.Item(j) Is DBNull.Value Then
                            worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Value = ""
                        Else
                            If k = 0 Then
                                worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "@"
                                worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Value = r.Item(j).ToString()
                            Else
                                worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Value = r.Item(j)
                            End If
                        End If
                       End If
                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                Next
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved condition (If Not r.Item(10).ToString().Contains("*") Then) (where r.Item(10) is my col number.) to out of the  For Each r As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows loop.

```
            Dim i As Integer = p + 1
            Dim a As Integer = 0
            For Each r As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                If Not r.Item(10).ToString().Contains("*") Then
                    k = 0
                    For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                        If Not skip.Contains(j) Then
                            If r.Item(j) Is DBNull.Value Then
                                worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Value = ""
                            Else
                                If k = 0 Then
                                    worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "@"
                                    worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Value = r.Item(j).ToString()
                                Else
                                    worksheet5.Cells(i, k + 1).Value = r.Item(j)
                                End If
                            End If
                            End If
                            k = k + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
```